# Is there a method for differentiating informative comments from commented out code?

Tags: javascript, comments

Throughout the course of programming, you will end up with some comments that explain code and some comments that are removing code:

```js
// A concise description 
const a = Boolean(obj);
//b = false;
```

Is there a good method to quickly parse which is which?

I've played around with using 3 `/`'s and `/** */` for descriptive comments.

I've also used a VSCode plugin to highlight `//TODO:` and `//FIXME:`

Comment: As a note, `///` and `/** ... */` comments are also used by some documentation generators, such as Doxygen or JSDoc.  If you use them or similar tools, you may not be able to use that kind of comment for descriptive comments that aren't intended to be part of the documentation.

Comment: In javascript most lines of code will probably end with a semicolon. Unless your comments do to, that seems pretty simple, and you can write a script to check for that easily too;

Answer (score 191, accepted):

There is a very simple solution to this: *remove the commented-out code.*

Really, there are only two good reasons to comment out code: to test something/make a fix, or to save code you might use later.  If you're testing or fixing something, remove the commented out code as soon as you're done with the test or fix.  If you're saving code you might use later, make it first-class code and put it somewhere such as a library where it can be put to good use.

Comment: Also, if the code has been checked in: just remove it. If you ever need it back, source control has got you covered

Comment: When code is removed nobody notices it ever existed. That makes it harder to recover. There is value in leaving commented code, especially if it seems likely that it will be used in the future.

Comment: @usr: *When code is removed nobody notices it ever existed* - and to my experience, in 99% of all real-world cases that is the right thing. In 1%, there may be some value in the outcommented lines, however, if commented-out code stays in for several weeks or months (or longer), chances are high it won't even compile any more due to refactorings of the active code lines. The "pontential value for future uses" argument is often used as a wrong excuse by people who have an emotional problem of stripping things out of the codebase for which they had invested some hours of brainwork.

Comment: I never commit commented code without additional explanatory comments.  There are rare situations where you might want the code back in the near term, but every single one of those is exceptional and requires an explanation for future developers (or future you).  90% of my comments are "Removed because it appears to be unused.  Delete after Nov 2021 if there are no problems"

Comment: @usr IMHO in all such cases it's better to actually write down the ideas behind the code in a descriptive comment. In this way anyone looking there can learn something. If they just see a bunch of loops doing nothing they understand what's the value? They have to reverse engineer it, then they will be in doubt about whether the code is commented because is incomplete, or bugged or not needed now/part of a future feature? 99% of the cases when you want to save code for later you want to `git stash save 'explanation'` and `git stash pop` when you go back at working on there-

Comment: @JamesBeninger in many cases where it makes sense to keep code, the time span is either so short that you can just keep it in your local git stash. If not it's often better to create a branch that has the code where the branch name and potentially a commit message adding the code explain the background. That way it's easy to keep code that belongs together in multiple places available, it will only be removed together (by deleting the branch) and nobody needs to regularly stumble over the outcommented lines and waste brain computation time on understanding the comments.

Comment: @JamesBeninger Granted, there may remain very few cases where you want to quickly share test code with people not experienced with git to exchange a patch etc or you cannot use a local stash as you switch machines etc. But those are in my experience really really rare. I don't remember to have come across a good use-case for commented out code since I started to use git.

Comment: _"Ideally, comments should only be used to explain aspects of the code that may not be clear from the source code itself. Code that is commented-out may become out of date, which may lead to confusion when maintaining the code."_ That's from a MISRA guideline. Most safe coding standards I've read say the same thing about commented code: bad idea.

Comment: My colleague once put "There was code here that did X but I removed it" when we removed some feature for the time being. That worked really well; you knew it was in source history for that file, but it wasn't bothering you.

Comment: A third really good reason to leave commented out code: it's subtly wrong, and you don't want the next person to (re)introduce anticipated incorrect behavior.  A big comment showing the incorrect code and explaining why it's wrong can go a very long way to preventing this problem.

Comment: I've occasionally used commented out code to show examples of correct usage of the active code. But that's no different from API docs in comments.

Comment: @Kevin: That's not commented-out code.  It won't run properly if you un-comment it.  It's just a code sample: sensible documentation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sometimes the API is simple enough that the snippet *will* run. But you're right to point out that "whether the snippet runs" is not the point.

Comment: Your answer sort of leads you back to the same question: if you agree that commented code should not make it to the master branch (or the repo in general), then it's beneficial to have it automatically removed. But to have it automatically removed, you need to distinguish commented text from commented code; hence the question on how to distinguish between it.

Comment: @flater: Who is discussing automatic removal?

Comment: @RobertHarvey "never" and "always" rules can easily be automated. "Sometimes" rules need manual oversight. I didn't say automatic removal is inherently required, but it's quite obviously beneficial over having to manually check if someone left commented code in any of the commits. To that extent, a way to identify it without needing a human to manually check every (changed) file makes life easier, which still leads to wanting to automate the search for commented code.

Comment: @Flater: The only way I can think of to do that is to apply a parser to the comments to see if they are code.

Comment: @marstato I hear the "just look back in source control" frequently, and it's complete nonsense. Unless you know _exactly_ where and what to look for it's next to impossible to find. As often as not it's a better use of time to just reimplement it.

Comment: @Kevjn: I'm not saying that you should spend 2 hours looking for deleted code before writing something new. But if you're working on the same project for a longer time and can remember "wait, at least half a year ago we had code doing this" you can spend some time. Otherwise I agree: just rewrite

Answer (score 45):

Adding to [@RobertHarvey's excellent answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/394288/13162) I believe there is only one legitimate reason I've ever encountered for saving commented code to source control, even temporarily: in case of **non-obvious replacement code which should not or cannot be used right now for some reason.** Even then most of the comment should be the *explanation,* not the replacement code. This could be a bug or a feature of the language which is not yet considered stable. It might look something like this:

```
# TODO: Replace with `foo = frobnicate(bar)` once <link.to/bug> is fixed
foo = [some complex workaround]
```

In this case, the work has already been done, but you can't yet take advantage of it, so deleting it means someone would have to rediscover it later. The same goes for [suboptimal solutions which may seem superior on the face of it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394287/is-there-a-method-for-differentiating-informative-comments-from-commented-out-co/394314?noredirect=1#comment868430_394314) or [conscious trade-offs against similar solutions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/394287/is-there-a-method-for-differentiating-informative-comments-from-commented-out-co/394314?noredirect=1#comment868442_394314).

Caution: Don't litter your code with alternative solutions. Every task can be done in infinitely many different ways, and it's not cost-effective to explore this space for a long time for every change. Code reviews can be a good place to discover such missing comments, when your colleague suggests an improvement which you have already discovered to be suboptimal.

Comment: The flip side of this is that sometimes you need to explain _why_ you aren't using `frobnicate(bar)`, so that no one will come along and try to "fix" your "inelegant" code.  So you show them that you know that in a perfect world, the `frobnicate` function would be the way to go, but you know from painful experience it doesn't work correctly.  There may be no expectation whatsoever that the third party even considers it a bug, much less worth fixing; you still need to leave a comment to future programmers (including yourself) about why you didn't take the obvious approach.

Comment: A related situation is that there may be two ways of doing something, one of which will process valid data much faster than the other, and one of which will offer more useful diagnostics if, for whatever reason, it receives invalid data.  If the program is part of a process that should only feed it data which is "guaranteed" to be valid, but something in the process isn't working properly, having available a version which is slower, but offers better diagnostics, can make it much easier to determine what's going wrong.

Answer (score 20):

Hmm, I read this question slightly differently from Robert who correctly asserts that commented out code should be removed.

If, however, you are looking for a convention to mark code for later removal, an old favorite of mine is:

`//b = false; //TODO: remove`

Some IDE's flag `//TODO:` comments or can be taught to. If not, it's usually a searchable string. It's best to follow whatever convention your shop has established because this can be done several ways. Every code base should do this one way. Keeps it searchable.

> quickly parse which is which?

Without that mark the automated way to do this is with the compiler. If stripping the comment off produces code that compiles, it must have been commented code. Writing an IDE plugin that checks that wouldn't be hard. But it will leave buggy commented code behind.

This is why it's better to simply mark commented out code as code the moment you comment it out. This lets you work non-destructively while you decide if you really want it gone. Since we all get interrupted, and are somewhat forgetful, don't be surprised if some lines get checked in while in that state.  If they do it's nice that they're at least clearly marked and searchable. Keyboard macros have helped me with this in the past. It's hard to get interrupted in the middle of this if you can do it with a single keystroke.

You can take this as far as enshrining the mark in your continuous integration tests. Oops, I'm trying to check in with outstanding TODO's again.

Comment: Instead of seeing if comments compile to label them as code, you could run comments through a natural language processor and label the ones that parse as a sentence or noun phrase in the language your team speaks.

Comment: @TheHansinator that sounds good but my experience with my cellphones auto correct relationship with my coder jargon makes me cautious.

Comment: I imagine that the NLP used to parse code comments would be a lot better than the NLP that powers autocorrect, simply because the computer has the entire sentence to work with and isn't trying to correct spelling errors. Not to mention that the false negative is better here, too - as long as a human is able to review the comment before deletion, they can just rewrite the comment, as opposed to not being alerted to useless gobbledygook.

Comment: w.r.t parsing: `double buffer (flip on)` -> C prototype or ultra-terse English? can't tell without context, not a correct whole construct in either language. Some false positives and negatives are inevitable, when comments by their nature don't constrain the form of their content in either direction.

Answer (score 8):

I use preprocessor directives to remove code, not comments at all:

```
//comment
active_code();
#if FALSE
inactive_code();
#endif
```

This makes a very easy thing to search for, and my syntax highlighter treats it as a comment.  I can even collapse it into a single line: `#if FALSE(...)`

You can expand on that idea to have several options:

```
#if OPTION == 0
code_for_option_0();
#elif OPTION == 1
code_for_option_1();
#else
code_for_all_other_options();
#endif
```

And compile-time error-checking:

```
#if FOO >= 5
#error FOO should be less than 5!
#endif
```

Of course, you don't want to go overboard on this, or it becomes difficult to tell what's actually getting compiled and what isn't.  But you get the idea, and it's the same problem as for commented code anyway...as long as you only use it statically.  If your conditions are dynamic, it's worse.

---

To determine which is which in an existing codebase that didn't consider this problem at all, I don't think there is a universal solution.  You'll have to find patterns yourself and probably code a regex to find them.

Comment: What in the world would this be good for? Do you need to compile multiple versions?

Comment: @Tvde1 That's one possibility, and a potential nightmare if you don't manage it *really* well.  But the alternative is possibly worse.  If you have multiple copies of almost the same code, one for each variation on a common theme, then you have to maintain them separately and keep them in sync.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but they all have some variation of either the complex configuration problem or the independent copy problem: Are you sure that a bugfix got to all of the independent copies?  What if not, and another feature gets added, that is then broken by the bugfix that was known before the feature but not ported until now?

Comment: That only works if you *have* a pre-processing step like C. The question is about `javascript`. You could do some pre-processing but it's going to stretch the build system's capabilities and it's also non-standard. If you don't have a build system or the build system doesn't at all support parsing and executing code, you will not be able to implement this solution. Finally, it doesn't even address the question - commented out code is not strictly equivalent to code that is conditionally activated. It could be a leftover that's not meant to be enabled.

Comment: Conditional activation is only an extension of the answer and not the answer itself.  Otherwise I would edit it to include the comments that extend it even further.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer stating that old code should be removed rather than commented out where possible, however I have observed a convention for those few occasions when commented-out code is needed.

(My basis is C# but this can be applied to any C-syntax language eg java)

```
// An explanatory comment has a space between the comment marker and the content.

// The following lines are commented out code so do not have the space (except where indented).
//var a = something();
//if(a==2) {
//   doSomethingElse();
//}
```

Comment: This depends totally on style: When I comment out code, I generally add the `//` to the first column, and since virtually all code is indented, the result is virtually always that the comment starts with some tabs. Normal comments don't get a leading space from me, unless there are already other comments with a leading space in the vicinity. So, your method would fail abysmally on comments that I produced, and any method designed to recognize my comment patterns would fail abysmally on yours.

Comment: @cmaster Ah I see, I think I misunderstood the question. I provided a simple way of formatting the comments in such a way that they can be easily parsed for type, which isn't what was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I am interpreting the question different still, thinking you want to find commented out code.

C-style code is bound to have semi-colons in it while comment is unlikely to have semi-colons in it. So for single line commented-out code you could use this regular expression:

```
\s*\/\/[\s\S]*;
```

For multi-line commented-out code it could be

```
\/\*[^\;]*;[^\;]*\*\/
```

Note Visual Studio is a bit peculiar about line breaks in regular expressions, they do not count as whitespace, you need to specify an explicit \n.

Comment: I found `^\s*//.*;\s*$` as proposed in [The Blog of Colin Mackay](https://colinmackay.scot/2013/10/17/tip-of-the-day-quickly-finding-commented-out-code-in-c-like-languages/) to work very well. Also, doing a commit before deleting code helps avoiding commenting it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an editor with a compiler running in the background (like Xcode and Clang), you can just try to compile the text of the comment. For example”a concise description” gives errors, “b = false;” doesn’t. You could then use different syntax highlighting.

A simpler method would be an IDE plugin that uses some heuristics, like multiple words in a row other than keywords points to comments, matched curly braced point to code etc.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have covered variations on the "don't comment out code" theme. But sometimes you do still want it around for reference.

If you genuinely need the code to stay around, a better solution is to surround the code with "#if 0 ... #endif", ideally with a comment to say why. This is the recommended strategy from various coding standards, including MISRA.

Answer (score -3):

Simple, at least for me - and in C/C++.  Comments enclosed in /* */ are informative.  Test code that is temporarily removed is commented out with leading //.

And there is good reason to leave test code in the file but commented out, at least in the sort of work I do.  Sooner or later someone will want a change made, which will need that code. Uncommenting a block takes one editor command, as does re-commenting it where you're finished.

Comment: There's also `#ifdef __DEBUG ... #endif`, or whatever custom definition you want to use.  `__DEBUG` is nice though, because you often only have to change the project configuration to get it.  But most IDE's let you define your own configurations as well, which can give you anything in that spot.

Comment: What do you mean by “test code”? Unit tests? Those shouldn't be commented out at all but kept _in the test suite_ and run as often as possible, regardless of whether somebody thinks it's necessary. Sure, it's easy to re-un-comment a piece of code, but it's even easier not not do anything at all and have the test suite already in place doing it...

Comment: Argh, **don't** do that. Commenting out code "to test something" will work perfectly fine 99 out of 100 times... and in the single case you'll forget to remove it (if it is no longer needed) or - even worse - forget to uncomment it (if it is needed) and things may get ugly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: No, I mean things like printf statements put in to check values.

Comment: @jamesqf you should never need that kind of stuff, that's what a debugger is there for. But even if you use `printf` / `cout` or similar for getting newly-written code right (which I'll admit I have done myself in the past), it's really not very effective to leave them there. If somebody want to make changes and knows which variables they need info about, it's quick and easy to write the `printf`s anew, whereas if that dev _doesn't_ know what's needed and just un-comments all those `printf` statements then the huge swath of text in the terminal likely won't help them either.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "you should never need that kind of stuff, that's what a debugger is there for", well no. Debugger is not always available. But you probably mean more generally, that logging should be done and controlled in some other way than commenting out the log lines when not needed (except for temporary local debugging which shall not be committed to version control).

Comment: @hyde well, yes; what I mean is, at the level where the programmer can comment/uncomment actual source code, a debugger (or REPL or whatever) should always be available. As you say, _logging_ has of course its validity/necessity, but proper logging should never require manual switching of lots of commenting-tokens.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Re "that's what a debugger is there for", somehow I suspect you may never have dealt with the sort of compute-intensive code that takes hours to run to the point of interest (even on a small test case) - and that's before factoring in the slowdowns that can be caused by running under a debugger.

Comment: As for the other comments about how I "should" do this or that, one of the more important  things I have learned in my programming career is that one size doesn't fit all.  The things you suggest are useful, sometimes.  Other times they're not.  Trying to adhere to one dogmatic method because some authority has told you that's what you "should" do is not IMHO the way to be productive.  (Unless that authority is paying your salary/consulting fees,  of course :-))

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Re "that's what a debugger is there for", somehow I suspect you may never have dealt with the sort of compute-intensive code that takes hours to run to the point of interest (even on a small test case) - and that's before factoring in the slowdowns that can be caused by running under a debugger.  As for that "huge swath of text in the terminal", perhaps you have heard of writing to files?  Or even output redirection?

Comment: @jamesqf oh, I have. (In fact I've had to deal with the kind of compute-intensive code that takes _days to run in parallel on a supercomputer_ to the point of interest.) I don't say debuggers are great fun, just that they're less clumsy than manually switched output statements. Ideally, you'd avoid retrieving any runtime internal-state information of the complete program at all but instead make sure beforehand all functions work – with stronger types and unit tests. Granted, that is neigh impossible in a language like C; I consider myself happy that I mostly work in Haskell and Coq nowadays.